# App Icon not showing in Organizer in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode6

I have a project created on Xcode 6.1.1 - using Asset Catalogs. Targeted for iOS 7. iPad only application.

My icons are showing fine in the simulator and on a device. But when I archive the project, the icons do not show up in the organizer. And subsequently do not show up in Test Flight or Crashlytics.

Icon files are all from a previous Xcode project, that did not have this issue. I have tried re-saving all the files. Making sure the asset catalog is targeted correctly, removing and reading the images. Restarting Xcode. Restarting my computer. Checking then copy bundle resources.

I am at a complete stand still. No idea how to correct this. Any help or tidbits are appreciated.

Comment: Did you cleaned (cmd + K), deleted derived data (~/Library/Developer/DerrivedData) and rebuilt the project?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your app's Info.plist file and check for the various Icon file entries. These should all refer to existing files in your project. You might need to copy the file into the root of your project for it to be found.

Since you have a previous project that worked, you can also compare with the Info.plist file from that project and look for missing entries.

[image]

Comment: I copied over the exact icon specifications from the previous apps plist once I couldn't get the asset catalog to work. Still no dice.

Comment: Did you try copying the file to the root of your project?

Comment: Also, are these 76pt icons?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete all the old files, and regenerate all the icons with a template - and drag them all into the asset catalog at once. Clean build. Finally worked.